# Angular 2+ and debounce

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

In AngularJS I was able to debounce a model by using ng-model options.

```
ng-model-options="{ debounce: 1000 }"
```

How can I debounce a model in Angular?
I tried to search for debounce in the docs but I couldn't find anything.

https://angular.io/search/#stq=debounce&stp=1

A solution would be to write my own debounce function, for example:

```
import {Component, Template, bootstrap} from 'angular2/angular2';

// Annotation section
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app'
})
@Template({
  url: 'app.html'
})
// Component controller
class MyAppComponent {
  constructor() {
    this.firstName = 'Name';
  }
    
  changed($event, el){
    console.log("changes", this.name, el.value);
    this.name = el.value;
  }

  firstNameChanged($event, first){
    if (this.timeoutId) window.clearTimeout(this.timeoutID);
    this.timeoutID = window.setTimeout(() => {
        this.firstName = first.value;
    }, 250)
  }
    
}
bootstrap(MyAppComponent);
```

And my html

```
<input type=text [value]="firstName" #first (keyup)="firstNameChanged($event, first)">
```

But I'm looking for a built in function, is there one in Angular?

Comment: This might be relevant https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/1773, not implented yet apparently.

Answer (score 236, accepted):

**Updated for RC.5**

With Angular 2 we can debounce using RxJS operator `debounceTime()` on a form control's `valueChanges` observable:

```ts
import {Component}   from '@angular/core';
import {FormControl} from '@angular/forms';
import {Observable}  from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/throttleTime';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/fromEvent';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<input type=text [value]="firstName" [formControl]="firstNameControl">
    <br>{{firstName}}`
})
export class AppComponent {
  firstName        = 'Name';
  firstNameControl = new FormControl();
  formCtrlSub: Subscription;
  resizeSub:   Subscription;
  ngOnInit() {
    // debounce keystroke events
    this.formCtrlSub = this.firstNameControl.valueChanges
      .debounceTime(1000)
      .subscribe(newValue => this.firstName = newValue);
    // throttle resize events
    this.resizeSub = Observable.fromEvent(window, 'resize')
      .throttleTime(200)
      .subscribe(e => {
        console.log('resize event', e);
        this.firstName += '*';  // change something to show it worked
      });
  }
  ngDoCheck() { console.log('change detection'); }
  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.formCtrlSub.unsubscribe();
    this.resizeSub  .unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

<kbd>[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/A8Ms99r7sazUeZS90z7K?p=preview)</kbd>

The code above also includes an example of how to throttle window resize events, as asked by @albanx in a comment below.

---

Although the above code is probably the Angular-way of doing it, it is not efficient.  Every keystroke and every resize event, even though they are debounced and throttled, results in change detection running.  In other words, **debouncing and throttling do not affect how often change detection runs**. (I found a [GitHub comment](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/1773#issuecomment-102078250) by Tobias Bosch that confirms this.)  You can see this when you run the plunker and you see how many times `ngDoCheck()` is being called when you type into the input box or resize the window. (Use the blue "x" button to run the plunker in a separate window to see the resize events.)

A more efficient technique is to create RxJS Observables yourself from the events, outside of Angular's "zone".  This way, change detection is not called each time an event fires. Then, in your subscribe callback methods, manually trigger change detection – i.e., you control when change detection is called:

```ts
import {Component, NgZone, ChangeDetectorRef, ApplicationRef, 
        ViewChild, ElementRef} from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/throttleTime';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/fromEvent';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<input #input type=text [value]="firstName">
    <br>{{firstName}}`
})
export class AppComponent {
  firstName = 'Name';
  keyupSub:  Subscription;
  resizeSub: Subscription;
  @ViewChild('input') inputElRef: ElementRef;
  constructor(private ngzone: NgZone, private cdref: ChangeDetectorRef,
    private appref: ApplicationRef) {}
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.ngzone.runOutsideAngular( () => {
      this.keyupSub = Observable.fromEvent(this.inputElRef.nativeElement, 'keyup')
        .debounceTime(1000)
        .subscribe(keyboardEvent => {
          this.firstName = keyboardEvent.target.value;
          this.cdref.detectChanges();
        });
      this.resizeSub = Observable.fromEvent(window, 'resize')
        .throttleTime(200)
        .subscribe(e => {
          console.log('resize event', e);
          this.firstName += '*';  // change something to show it worked
          this.cdref.detectChanges();
        });
    });
  }
  ngDoCheck() { console.log('cd'); }
  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.keyupSub .unsubscribe();
    this.resizeSub.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

<kbd>[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/E77SzTXvBnaBL4SzyOgh?p=preview)</kbd>

I use `ngAfterViewInit()` instead of `ngOnInit()` to ensure that `inputElRef` is defined.

[`detectChanges()`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ChangeDetectorRef-class.html#!#detectChanges-anchor) will run change detection on this component and its children. If you would rather run change detection from the root component (i.e., run a full change detection check) then use [`ApplicationRef.tick()`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ApplicationRef-class.html#!#tick-anchor) instead.  (I put a call to `ApplicationRef.tick()` in comments in the plunker.) Note that calling `tick()` will cause `ngDoCheck()` to be called.

Comment: @Mark Rajcok
I think instead of [value] , you should use [ngModel] , because [value] doesn't update the input value .

Comment: is there any generic debounce method (for example to apply on window resize event)?

Comment: I would add this two lines after `.debounceTime(1000)` just to improve that (later in the subscribe you'll already have the value):
`.map((event: any) => event.target.value)`
`.distinctUntilChanged()`

Comment: @MarkRajcok I believe the CD issue you described in your answer is resolved by https://github.com/angular/zone.js/pull/843

Comment: @MarkRajcok I used `this.ngzone.run(() => {});` to render response from `subscribe` method of a `httpRequest` invoked from `this.ngzone.runOutsideAngular` since `this.cdref.detectChanges()` was not aware of returned results. Don't know is it the correct way of doing this!

Comment: When would we need to unsubscribe to prevent memory leaks?

Comment: @slanden Yes, acccording to https://netbasal.com/when-to-unsubscribe-in-angular-d61c6b21bad3, we should unsubscribe from `.fromEvent()` subscriptions

Answer (score 201):

If you don't want to deal with `@angular/forms`, you can just use an RxJS [`Subject`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/gettingstarted/subjects.md) with change bindings.

#### view.component.html

```
<input [ngModel]='model' (ngModelChange)='changed($event)' />
```

#### view.component.ts

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { Component }   from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime';

export class ViewComponent {
    model: string;
    modelChanged: Subject<string> = new Subject<string>();

    constructor() {
        this.modelChanged
            .debounceTime(300) // wait 300ms after the last event before emitting last event
            .distinctUntilChanged() // only emit if value is different from previous value
            .subscribe(model => this.model = model);
    }

    changed(text: string) {
        this.modelChanged.next(text);
    }
}
```

This does trigger change detection. [For a way that doesn't trigger change detection, check out Mark's answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36849347/2456263)

---

### Update

[`.pipe(debounceTime(300), distinctUntilChanged())`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/pipe) is needed for rxjs 6.

Example:

```
   constructor() {
        this.modelChanged.pipe(
            debounceTime(300), 
            distinctUntilChanged())
            .subscribe(model => this.model = model);
    }
```

Comment: I prefer this solution! Worked with angular 2.0.0, rxjs 5.0.0-beta 12

Comment: Worked perfectly, simple and clear, no form involved. I'm on Angular 4.1.3, rxjs 5.1.1

Comment: I think this is superior solution since it has the option to work with forms if needed, but removes that dependency making implementation that much simpler. Thanks.

Comment: `.pipe(debounceTime(300), distinctUntilChanged())` is needed for rxjs 6

Comment: The solution saved me. I was using `keyUp` event on `input.nativeElement` in a `mat-table`, that stopped working when the number of columns was changed

Comment: Is there anyway to prevent change detection with this method?

Comment: Certainly it is possible to prevent change detection with this method, as I just recently adapted both this answer and the selected one, and worked just fine.
I even added an extra conditional check to maximize api rest call efficiency. Working on ng v. 7.x

Comment: distinctUntilChanged() is a life saver, otherwise your form values will refresh all the time and interrupt i.e. sending queryParams!

Comment: `import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';` gives error with angular 8. Use `import { Subject } from 'rxjs';`

Comment: Do you think we need to do unsubscribe or another thing on OnDestroy?

Answer (score 67):

Since the topic is old, most of the answers **don't work** on **Angular 6-13** and/or use other libs.
So here is a short and simple solution for Angular 6+ with RxJS.

Import the necessary stuff first:

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject, Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { debounceTime, distinctUntilChanged } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

Implement the `ngOnInit` and `ngOnDestroy`:

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  public notesText: string;
  public notesModelChanged: Subject<string> = new Subject<string>();
  private notesModelChangeSubscription: Subscription

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.notesModelChangeSubscription = this.notesModelChanged
      .pipe(
        debounceTime(2000),
        distinctUntilChanged()
      )
      .subscribe(newText => {
        this.notesText = newText;
        console.log(newText);
      });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.notesModelChangeSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

Use this way:

```
<input [ngModel]='notesText' (ngModelChange)='notesModelChanged.next($event)' />
```

P.S. For more complex and efficient solutions you might still want to check other answers.

Comment: @JustShadow Thank you! It was really helpful.

Comment: This works perfect on the first try. But when I delete the searched text somehow the next request takes too long to respond.

Comment: That's strange. It still works fine on my side. Could you please share more info or maybe open a new question for that?

Comment: hats off... thank you @JustShadow!
@SadikshaGautam must have already got the solution by now but for new ones... you might need to just lower the debouceTime(2000) from 2000 milliseconds to something lower, perhaps the usual delay which is 300milliseconds.

Comment: In Angular14 I'm getting:

```error TS2345: Argument of type 'Event' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.```

Comment: I found the issue - you have to have:

````import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';```` and also put FormsModule in the imports: attribute of your @NgModule that needs to use ngModel. You also must have a "name" attribute on your <input> element.

Answer (score 37):

It could be implemented as Directive

```
import { Directive, Input, Output, EventEmitter, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { NgControl } from '@angular/forms';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/distinctUntilChanged';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

@Directive({
  selector: '[ngModel][onDebounce]',
})
export class DebounceDirective implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  @Output()
  public onDebounce = new EventEmitter<any>();

  @Input('debounce')
  public debounceTime: number = 300;

  private isFirstChange: boolean = true;
  private subscription: Subscription;

  constructor(public model: NgControl) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription =
      this.model.valueChanges
        .debounceTime(this.debounceTime)
        .distinctUntilChanged()
        .subscribe(modelValue => {
          if (this.isFirstChange) {
            this.isFirstChange = false;
          } else {
            this.onDebounce.emit(modelValue);
          }
        });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }

}
```

use it like

```
<input [(ngModel)]="value" (onDebounce)="doSomethingWhenModelIsChanged($event)">
```

component sample

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sample',
  template: `
<input[(ngModel)]="value" (onDebounce)="doSomethingWhenModelIsChanged($event)">
<input[(ngModel)]="value" (onDebounce)="asyncDoSomethingWhenModelIsChanged($event)">
`
})
export class SampleComponent {
  value: string;

  doSomethingWhenModelIsChanged(value: string): void {
    console.log({ value });
  }

  async asyncDoSomethingWhenModelIsChanged(value: string): Promise<void> {
    return new Promise<void>(resolve => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('async', { value });
        resolve();
      }, 1000);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: with more imports, that worked for me:

import "rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime";
import "rxjs/add/operator/distinctUntilChanged";

Comment: This by far makes it the simplest to implement application wide

Comment: Isn't working checkout: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-debounce-example?file=src/app/app.module.ts

Comment: @Shyamal Parikh, it is working. You need to add (onDebounce)="doSomethingWhenModelIsChanged()"
and the implementation to the component

Comment: isFirstChange is used not to emit on initialize

Comment: A logger shows me my event `this.debounceEvent.emit(modelValue);` is emitted, but my `search(searchTerm: string): void` method is not called. Why do we need the `[(ngModel)]="searchTerm"` in `<input matInput [(ngModel)]="searchTerm" (appOnDebounce)="search($event)" placeholder="Search..." autocomplete="off">`?

Comment: I posted my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53648388/directive-event-not-being-received-by-the-component

Comment: It would be nice if you can update your answer and use the new [pipe syntax](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/v6/migration#operator-pipe-syntax)

Comment: Works in Angular 8 and rxjs 6.5.2 with the following changes. If you want to use the pipe syntax, change the following: `import 'rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/distinctUntilChanged';` to `import { debounceTime, distinctUntilChanged } from 'rxjs/operators';` and `this.model.valueChanges
        .debounceTime(this.debounceTime)
        .distinctUntilChanged()` to `this.model.valueChanges
                .pipe(
                    debounceTime(this.debounceTime),
                    distinctUntilChanged()
                )`

Comment: Works in Angular 9 and rxjs 6.5.4 with changes @kumaheiyama stated in his comment. Just don't forget to export the directive in the module where you're creating it. And don't forget to include the module you're creating this directive in, into the module where you are using it.

Comment: Also, a minor improvement. Instead of doing the `isFirstChange` check, you can just add a filter `filter(value => value != null)` as first in the `pipe()`. Another one would be to not do a search for less than, say, 2 characters. That would be another filter like this: `filter(value => value.length > 2)`. Imports: `import { debounceTime, distinctUntilChanged, map, filter } from 'rxjs/operators';`.

Answer (score 31):

Not directly accessible like in angular1 but you can easily play with NgFormControl and RxJS observables:

```
<input type="text" [ngFormControl]="term"/>

this.items = this.term.valueChanges
  .debounceTime(400)
  .distinctUntilChanged()
  .switchMap(term => this.wikipediaService.search(term));
```

This blog post explains it clearly:
http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/01/06/taking-advantage-of-observables-in-angular2.html

Here it is for an autocomplete but it works all scenarios.

Comment: but there is an error from service, this is not running again

Comment: I dont understand the example. `[...]`  is one-way target binding. Why can the container be notified of `valueChanges`? shouldn't it have to be sth. like `(ngFormControl)="..."`?

Answer (score 27):

You can *create* an RxJS (v.6) [Observable](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js%7EObservable.html#static-method-create) that does whatever you like.

#### view.component.html

```
<input type="text" (input)="onSearchChange($event.target.value)" />
```

#### view.component.ts

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { debounceTime, distinctUntilChanged } from 'rxjs/operators';

export class ViewComponent {
    searchChangeObserver;

  onSearchChange(searchValue: string) {

    if (!this.searchChangeObserver) {
      new Observable(observer => {
        this.searchChangeObserver = observer;
      }).pipe(debounceTime(300)) // wait 300ms after the last event before emitting last event
        .pipe(distinctUntilChanged()) // only emit if value is different from previous value
        .subscribe(console.log);
    }

    this.searchChangeObserver.next(searchValue);
  }  


}
```

Comment: Thanks that helped, however I think the import should be from `rsjs/Rx`, I had errors when using the import the way you wrote it... so in my case it's now: `import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';`

Comment: @ghiscoding It depends on the rxjs version. In version 6 it is: ```import { Observable } from 'rxjs';```.

Comment: Thanks! As an aside, you can just use one `pipe` call `pipe(debounceTime(300), distinctUntilChanged())`

Comment: searchChangeObserver is a Subscriber, so searchChangeSubscriber will be a better name.

Answer (score 16):

For anyone using lodash, it is extremely easy to [debounce](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#debounce) any function:

```
changed = _.debounce(function() {
    console.log("name changed!");
}, 400);
```

then just throw something like this into your template:

```
<(input)="changed($event.target.value)" />
```

Comment: or just (input)="changed($event.target.value)"

Comment: Thank you for answering with lodash :)

Comment: I believe this will still trigger the Angular change detection on every single change, regardless of the debouncing.

Answer (score 8):

Solution with initialization subscriber directly in event function:

```
import {Subject} from 'rxjs';
import {debounceTime, distinctUntilChanged} from 'rxjs/operators';

class MyAppComponent {
    searchTermChanged: Subject<string> = new Subject<string>();

    constructor() {
    }

    onFind(event: any) {
        if (this.searchTermChanged.observers.length === 0) {
            this.searchTermChanged.pipe(debounceTime(1000), distinctUntilChanged())
                .subscribe(term => {
                    // your code here
                    console.log(term);
                });
        }
        this.searchTermChanged.next(event);
    }
}
```

And html:

```
<input type="text" (input)="onFind($event.target.value)">
```

Comment: Works totally fine for angular 8 prime ng autocomplete textbox. Thanks a lot.

Comment: awesome answer ..keep it up

Answer (score 4):

I solved this by writing a debounce decorator. The problem described could be solved by applying the @debounceAccessor to the property's set accessor.

I've also supplied an additional debounce decorator for methods, which can be useful for other occasions.

This makes it very easy to debounce a property or a method. The parameter is the number of milliseconds the debounce should last, 100 ms in the example below.

```
@debounceAccessor(100)
set myProperty(value) {
  this._myProperty = value;
}


@debounceMethod(100)
myMethod (a, b, c) {
  let d = a + b + c;
  return d;
}
```

And here's the code for the decorators:

```
function debounceMethod(ms: number, applyAfterDebounceDelay = false) {

  let timeoutId;

  return function (target: Object, propName: string, descriptor: TypedPropertyDescriptor<any>) {
    let originalMethod = descriptor.value;
    descriptor.value = function (...args: any[]) {
      if (timeoutId) return;
      timeoutId = window.setTimeout(() => {
        if (applyAfterDebounceDelay) {
          originalMethod.apply(this, args);
        }
        timeoutId = null;
      }, ms);

      if (!applyAfterDebounceDelay) {
        return originalMethod.apply(this, args);
      }
    }
  }
}

function debounceAccessor (ms: number) {

  let timeoutId;

  return function (target: Object, propName: string, descriptor: TypedPropertyDescriptor<any>) {
    let originalSetter = descriptor.set;
    descriptor.set = function (...args: any[]) {
      if (timeoutId) return;
      timeoutId = window.setTimeout(() => {
        timeoutId = null;
      }, ms);
      return originalSetter.apply(this, args);
    }
  }
}
```

I added an additional parameter for the method decorator which let's you trigger the method AFTER the debounce delay. I did that so I could for instance use it when coupled with mouseover or resize events, where I wanted the capturing to occur at the end of the event stream. In this case however, the method won't return a value.

Answer (score 4):

We can create a [debounce] directive which overwrites ngModel's default viewToModelUpdate function with an empty one.

Directive Code

```
@Directive({ selector: '[debounce]' })
export class MyDebounce implements OnInit {
    @Input() delay: number = 300;

    constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef, private model: NgModel) {
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        const eventStream = Observable.fromEvent(this.elementRef.nativeElement, 'keyup')
            .map(() => {
                return this.model.value;
            })
            .debounceTime(this.delay);

        this.model.viewToModelUpdate = () => {};

        eventStream.subscribe(input => {
            this.model.viewModel = input;
            this.model.update.emit(input);
        });
    }
}
```

How to use it

```
<div class="ui input">
  <input debounce [delay]=500 [(ngModel)]="myData" type="text">
</div>
```

Comment: What's the namespace of Observable? Mine is coming without the "fromEvent" method

Answer (score 3):

HTML file:

```
<input [ngModel]="filterValue"
       (ngModelChange)="filterValue = $event ; search($event)"
        placeholder="Search..."/>
```

TS file:

```
timer = null;
time = 250;
  search(searchStr : string) : void {
    clearTimeout(this.timer);
    this.timer = setTimeout(()=>{
      console.log(searchStr);
    }, time)
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

**DebounceTime in Angular 7 with RxJS v6**

**Source [Link](http://www.freakyjolly.com/angular-7-6-add-debounce-time-using-rxjs-6-x-x-to-optimize-search-input-for-api-results-from-server/)**

**Demo [Link](https://freakyjolly.com/demo/Angular/Angular7/NG7DebounceTime/)**

[image]

In HTML Template

```
<input type="text" #movieSearchInput class="form-control"
            placeholder="Type any movie name" [(ngModel)]="searchTermModel" />
```

In component

```
    ....
    ....
    export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

    @ViewChild('movieSearchInput') movieSearchInput: ElementRef;
    apiResponse:any;
    isSearching:boolean;

        constructor(
        private httpClient: HttpClient
        ) {
        this.isSearching = false;
        this.apiResponse = [];
        }

    ngOnInit() {
        fromEvent(this.movieSearchInput.nativeElement, 'keyup').pipe(
        // get value
        map((event: any) => {
            return event.target.value;
        })
        // if character length greater then 2
        ,filter(res => res.length > 2)
        // Time in milliseconds between key events
        ,debounceTime(1000)        
        // If previous query is diffent from current   
        ,distinctUntilChanged()
        // subscription for response
        ).subscribe((text: string) => {
            this.isSearching = true;
            this.searchGetCall(text).subscribe((res)=>{
            console.log('res',res);
            this.isSearching = false;
            this.apiResponse = res;
            },(err)=>{
            this.isSearching = false;
            console.log('error',err);
            });
        });
    }

    searchGetCall(term: string) {
        if (term === '') {
        return of([]);
        }
        return this.httpClient.get('http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=' + term + '&apikey=' + APIKEY,{params: PARAMS.set('search', term)});
    }

    }
```

Comment: Thank you for that amazing blog link!

Answer (score 3):

You could also solve this by using a decorators, For an instance by using the debounce decorator from [utils-decorator](https://github.com/vlio20/utils-decorators#debounce-method) lib (`npm install utils-decorators`):

```
import {debounce} from 'utils-decorators';

class MyAppComponent {

  @debounce(500)
  firstNameChanged($event, first) {
   ...
  }
}
```

Comment: I like how clean this one looks

Answer (score 2):

Simple solution would be to create a directive which you can apply to any control.

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Input, Renderer, HostListener, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { NgControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
    selector: '[ngModel][debounce]',
})
export class Debounce 
{
    @Output() public onDebounce = new EventEmitter<any>();

    @Input('debounce') public debounceTime: number = 500;

    private modelValue = null;

    constructor(public model: NgControl, el: ElementRef, renderer: Renderer){
    }

    ngOnInit(){
        this.modelValue = this.model.value;

        if (!this.modelValue){
            var firstChangeSubs = this.model.valueChanges.subscribe(v =>{
                this.modelValue = v;
                firstChangeSubs.unsubscribe()
            });
        }

        this.model.valueChanges
            .debounceTime(this.debounceTime)
            .distinctUntilChanged()
            .subscribe(mv => {
                if (this.modelValue != mv){
                    this.modelValue = mv;
                    this.onDebounce.emit(mv);
                }
            });
    }
}
```

usage would be

```
<textarea [ngModel]="somevalue"   
          [debounce]="2000"
          (onDebounce)="somevalue = $event"                               
          rows="3">
</textarea>
```

Comment: This class is far from compiling in `Angular 7`.

Answer (score 1):

Spent hours on this, hopefully I can save someone else some time.  To me the following approach to using `debounce` on a control is more intuitive and easier to understand for me.  It's built on the angular.io docs solution for autocomplete but with the ability for me to intercept the calls without having to depend on tying the data to the DOM.

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/eSHZE7)

A use case scenario for this might be checking a username after it's typed to see if someone has already taken it, then warning the user.

Note: don't forget, `(blur)="function(something.value)` might make more sense for you depending on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best solution I have found till now. Updates the `ngModel`on `blur` and `debounce`

```
import { Directive, Input, Output, EventEmitter,ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { NgControl, NgModel } from '@angular/forms';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime'; 
import 'rxjs/add/operator/distinctUntilChanged';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/fromEvent';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Directive({
    selector: '[ngModel][debounce]',
})
export class DebounceDirective {
    @Output()
    public onDebounce = new EventEmitter<any>();

    @Input('debounce')
    public debounceTime: number = 500;

    private isFirstChange: boolean = true;

    constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef, private model: NgModel) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        const eventStream = Observable.fromEvent(this.elementRef.nativeElement, 'keyup')
            .map(() => {
                return this.model.value;
            })
            .debounceTime(this.debounceTime);

        this.model.viewToModelUpdate = () => {};

        eventStream.subscribe(input => {
            this.model.viewModel = input;
            this.model.update.emit(input);
        });
    }
}
```

as borrowed from https://stackoverflow.com/a/47823960/3955513

Then in HTML:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="hero.name" 
        [debounce]="3000" 
        (blur)="hero.name = $event.target.value"
        (ngModelChange)="onChange()"
        placeholder="name">
```

On `blur` the model is explicitly updated using plain javascript.

Example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-debounce-working