# rxjs - how do I debounceTime for multiple incoming events target multiple different objects dependent of an internal identifier

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable

regarding to the following topic: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39960980/4457758

how can I adjust this flow for multiple incoming events which are depending lets say on a given object id ... So I am getting a bunch of events with different object ids and I want to debounce them for every target object Id every xxx milli seconds? So I need for every object id a separate debouncer responsible only for one object id?

Comment: post your code...

Comment: I think you can use `debounce` for this: `src$.pipe(debounce(({ id }) => timer(getTimeForId(id))))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `groupBy` to group incoming events by some parameter. Then debounce each group separately.

```ts
import { timer } from 'rxjs';
import { debounce, mergeMap, groupBy } from 'rxjs/operators';

eventStream$.pipe(
  groupBy(event => event.id),
  mergeMap(group$ => group$.pipe(
    debounce(event => timer(idToMillis(event.id)))
  ))
)
```

Comment: Thanks :) groupBy was the operator I was looking for :)