# Angular Promise - debounceTime behavior

Tags: angular, angular-promise, debouncing

I'm using angular 7 and I've the following (working) code.

```
    import { Http } from '@angular/http';


    public httpService: Http;
    (....)

    public callAction(): Promise<void> {
        let r = this.httpService.post(url, panelData);

        return r.toPromise().then((response: { json: () => any; }) => {
            if (response.json()) {
                this.processResponse(panel, response.json());
            }
        }).catch((reason: any) => {
            throw reason;
        });
    }
```

The method *this.httpService.post* returns an *Observable< Response >*.

I'm trying to avoid multiple server calls and for that I'm trying to use the [debounce behavior](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/debouncetime.html).

I added the debounceTime on my Observable but it doesn't work when the **Promise** is called.

```
let r = this.httpService.post(url, panelData).debounceTime(5000);
return r.toPromise().then()
```

I know that I'm not subscribing the Observable but when I call the toPromise() should this behavior be "imported" to the promise?

PS- I also try with a pipe

```
let r = this.httpService.post(url, panelData).pipe(debounceTime(5000));
```

Comment: you must use the debounce operator into a pipe() as described into your link.

Comment: I tested with the pipe and it still not working -> let r = this.httpService.post(url, panelData).pipe(debounceTime(5000));

Comment: which angular version are you using? v5?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44183519/cant-make-debouncetime-or-throttletime-to-work-on-an-angular-http-request

Comment: I'm using angular v7

Comment: you should use `HttpClient` instead of deprecated `Http`. I think it may be the solution. Haven't worked with the latter, but with `HttpClient` I can pipe it

Comment: Also you should reverse the operations. What you are debouncing is the response from the server

Comment: Yes, it make sense. I'll change this. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to have `let r = this.httpService.post(url, panelData).debounceTime(5000);` outside your `callAction()` function and instead sit as a separate function/property of the class.
What is occurring is every time `callAction()` function is called a new debounce observable `r` is being created, instead you need to call the same one each time:

```js
import { Http } from '@angular/http';


public httpService: Http;
(....)

let r = this.httpService.post(url, panelData).debounceTime(5000);

public callAction(): Promise<void> {
    return this.r.toPromise().then((response: { json: () => any; }) => {
        if (response.json()) {
            this.processResponse(panel, response.json());
        }
    }).catch((reason: any) => {
        throw reason;
    });
}
```