# Angular 2 change variables in class by input

Tags: angular, input

I need some help with setting variables in class by text input,

```
nameChange(str){
    this.service.setName(str);
    console.log(str);
}
```

there is a example class, which modify variable, so how should input looks like, when I want just to modify variable anytime the input changes?

Comment: If you are looking for more fine-grained control, have a look at this post:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32051273/angular2-and-debounce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can intercept input property changes with a setter, try this:

// component:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-component',
    template: '<h3> My component </h3>'
})

export class MyComponent {
    @Input()
    set name(str: string) {
        this.service.setName(str);
        console.log(str);
    }
}
```

// HTML where component is used:

```
<my-component [name]="Bombasto"></my-component>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use two way databinding.

Example:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="property">

<p>{{property}}</p>
```

Take a look [here](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/10/13/two-way-data-binding-in-angular-2.html).

If you want to call a function like the one in your code, use this:

```
<input (input)="nameChange($event.target.value)">
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to use **ngOnChange** Event in this case as below. So whenever your input variable `myVar` value change it will call `ngOnChanges` event

```
@Input() myVar:any;

ngOnChanges(changes: any) {
    if (changes.myVar != null && changes.myVar.currentValue != null) {
       //your logic to update any variable or other....
    }
}
```