# Angular trigger call on stop typing

Tags: angular

I wanted to reuse my working `jQuery` function in Angular which has two functions, one called on `keyup` other on `keydown`

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="filterOptions.SearchValue" (keyup)="onFilter($event)" (keydown)="resetCounter()" class="form-control">
```

So that the counter gets reset every time on `keydown`. However this doesn't work:

```
timer = 0;

onFilter(event: any) {
    if (!HelperService.keypressFilter(event))
        return;

    console.log(this.timer);

    clearTimeout(this.timer);
    this.timer = setTimeout(this.resetValues(), 2000);
}

resetCounter(){
    console.log(this.timer);
    clearTimeout(this.timer);
    console.log(this.timer);
}
```

Each of the 3 console logs write the same number in the console, and they do so incrementally (i.e. 0 0 0, 3 3 3, 24 24 24...) after each key press. Those numbers have nothing to do with milliseconds. How can I make it work?

Comment: The numbers of `this.timeout` are for javascript and do not mean milliseconds. Just add `this.filterOptions.SearchValue = ""` before `clearTimeout` in `resetCounter()` and it should work. Let me know if it doesn't.

Comment: that just clears the input field and I can't enter more than one letter because it deletes it

Comment: This is basically a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32051273/angular2-and-debounce

Comment: I found a simpler solution, I'll post it

Answer (score -3, accepted):

So the solution was to utilize Angular `setTimeout()` function:

```
timer: any;

onFilter(event: any) {
    if (!HelperService.keypressFilter(event))
        return;

    clearTimeout(this.timer);
    this.timer = setTimeout(() => { this.resetValues() }, 200)
}

resetCounter() {
    clearTimeout(this.timer);
}
```