# kill $timeout and reset after every keypress

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Let's assume I have some inputs with their ng-models

```
<input type="text" ng-model="vm.man.name">
<input type="text" ng-model="vm.man.surName">
```

In my controller I have object `vm.man={};`.
 I want to do the following:
I want to put $watch on my `vm.man`, 
so if I press some key inside my `<input>`, it should wait 3 seconds and then send response to the server. However, if I pressed some key, and during 3 seconds I pressed another key it should  wait 3 seconds and then respond to the server. Here is what I have already done:

```
 $scope.$watch(()=>vm.man, function (newVal, oldVal) {
     if(angular.isUndefined(newVal)) {
         return console.log("newVal is Undefined")
     }else{
        vm.timer1= $timeout(function () {
         vm.someFunctionThatRespondsToServer();
         }, 3000);
     }
 }, true);
```

The problem I have now, it creates response per keypress. for example I pressed `a` in my `input` it responds a, then I pressed `b` it responds `ab` and etc.
I want to get something like this: I pressed `a` it waits 3 seconds if there is no other keypresses, it responds, or I pressed `a` and then after 2 seconds, lets say I pressed `b` it waits 3 seconds and then responds `ab` if there were no other keypresses during 3seconds.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In Angular 1/2 you can use function from Lodash `debounce`. Here is link and example: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#debounce

In Angular 2 RC5 and newer you can use `debounceTime`.
More details here 
[Angular and debounce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32051273/angular-and-debounce)

Answer (score 0):

There is built in functionality for that.  You want to add a debounce to the input that your ng-model is associated with. You do this specifically by adding a property called `ng-model-options`.  The following should work:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="vm.man.name" ng-model-options="{debounce: 200}">
<input type="text" ng-model="vm.man.surName" ng-model-options="{debounce: 200}">
```

This adds a 200ms debounce(delay) before the model is updated. Once you do this, you can remove that timeout in the watch function. There are a few other properties that you can play around using `ng-model-options` as well.  [Go here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions) for more info.

Comment: thanks for your reply, anyway it does not work, it still sends two response to server if I press any keys 2 times

Comment: That should work, did you increase the value?  I had it at 200 but maybe you want 500ms instead.