# call keyup event with delay in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have text box and assigned to it `keyup` event a search function but I want it to happen with delay, not on every keypress

here is the html code :

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="searchedKPI" (keyup)="searchConfigTree()">
```

and here is ts code :

```
list = list.filter(item => item.label.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(this.searchedKPI.toLocaleLowerCase())).slice();
```

and here is the example I wanted to search "text" string but the event happens 4 times, I want to this happens once only for "text" string :

[image]

what the solution?

Comment: what is wrong ?

Comment: i want to this happens once only for "text" string

Comment: try using debounce....!

Comment: this may help https://stackoverflow.com/a/36849347/5621827

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Welcome to the [**Observable's world**](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/). Just use Observable to get the desired result. Get the reference of your input in the component and use this code. `debounceTime` will let the event to trigger at least after `1 second` from the previous trigger. It will let you not to fire on every `keyup` when user types fast.

```
Observable.fromEvent(yourInput, 'keyup').debounceTime(1000).subscribe(value => /* */)
```

In the `subscribe` method you can write your logic. The `value` is the value of the input.

Comment: Getting error `Observable.fromEvent is not a function` - using rxjs 6.3.3

Comment: @amphetamachine use only `fromEvent`

Comment: Using `rxjs` higher than 6 version requires just `fromEvent` instead of `Observable.fromEvent`

Comment: thanks for your help, it help me a lot =D but complement with

Answer (score 13):

View template.html

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="searchedKPI" (keyup)="searchConfigTree()" #something>
```

component.ts (do not forget  implement the AfterViewInit)

```
     source: any;
     @ViewChild("something") something:ElementRef; 

     ngAfterViewInit(): void {
                this.source = fromEvent(this.something.nativeElement, 'keyup');
                this.source.pipe(debounceTime(1200)).subscribe(c => 
                {
                          list = list.filter(item => item.label.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(this.searchedKPI.toLocaleLowerCase())).slice();
                }
                );
              }
```

Comment: what is 'this.source' in this context?

Comment: @TorstenN. Hello, it's the `Subscription` object output of the `fromEvent(..) function. 
it can also be used to end the subscription in `ngOnDestroy(..) { }`  by calling `this.source.unsubscribe()`whenever we no longer use the actual component to prevent memory leaking issues.

Answer (score 1):

**This solution works for me**

View Template.html

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Filter..." class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="filter" (input)="searchChange($event.target.value, true)">
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" (click)="searchChange(filter, false)"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
```

Comonent.ts

```
  filter= '';
  private timer: any;

  searchChange(filter: string, to = false) {
    filter = filter.toLowerCase();

    if (to) {
      clearTimeout(this.timer);

      this.timer = setTimeout(() => {
        this.valuesFilter = this.allValues.filter(f => f.field.toLowerCase().includes(filter));
      }, 400);
    } else {
      this.valuesFilter = this.allValues.filter(f => f.field.toLowerCase().includes(filter));
    }
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

cant we use timeout function?

```
(keyup)="keyupFunc()" --> html
keyup() {
       timeout((your function code), delay_time_you_need);
   } --> ts
```

Comment: this solution is not working when `keyup()` happens multiple at the same time.