# Debouncing entire form in angular 6

Tags: angular

I recently switched from angularJs to Angular 6.

In angularJs, it was quite easy to add a debounce timer via `ng-model-options`. 
However, in Angular 6 I fail to find any method that does the same.

Im currently building a form using the template-driven approach with a bunch of validator-directives.

Did something go over my head? Do I have to use Reactive Form to debounce?

While quite a few questions here on SO discuss this problematic, I havent yet seen one that has the angular 6 context. 
It seems like a lot was changed in angular 6 regarding observables and rxjs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular and debounce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32051273/angular-and-debounce)

Comment: Solution for template driven forms: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40777621/330242