# How to observe for a property change in rxjs?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I Have a angular6 app with a simple input tag:

```
<input type="text" name="searchBox" [(ngModel)]="searchTerm" class="form-control" />
```

I would like to make a observable of the `searchTerm` property to add  some operators like `debounce`, etc ,etc.

How can I do that ( Without using the `ReactiveForms` ) ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular and debounce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32051273/angular-and-debounce)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few ways you can accomplish this. The easiest I've found is as follows:

Template should contain:

```
<input
  #searchInput
  [(ngModel)]="searchTerm"
  type="text"
  (keyup)="onChange(searchInput.value)" />
```

Component should have:

```
  import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
  import { debounceTime, distinctUntilChanged } from 'rxjs/operators';

  @Output() inputChanged: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();
  input = new Subject<string>();

  constructor() {
    this.input
        .pipe(debounceTime(300))
        .pipe(distinctUntilChanged())
        .subscribe(input => this.emitInputChanged(input));
  }

  onChange(input: string) {
     this.input.next(input);
  }
```

The `Subject` is subscribable. You can pipe in your other functions(like `debounce`) and then can emit changes from it at the end of the chain. I don't know what you are using the `ngModel` for, but since you have it in your question I left it. Any component that is listening to the output of `inputChanged` will get the updated value after the debounce occurs.

Comment: whats the connection between the Subject with the view input?

Comment: Sorry, I was typing too quickly. I left out a few lines. I have updated the answer. Hope this helps.

Comment: Great! Works like a charm