# wait for all pending request resolved and take value from last

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a method `getData()` inside Angular app which calls on click every time when `asc > desc` sorting in the table is changed. If I click it 10 times in a row I will make 10 get request and data will assign to table every time when the request is resolved, so it makes it blinking till the last request. How can I waiting for data only for the last request and ignore another?

```
 this.getData() {
   this.endpointsService.getData(reqParams).pipe(
      takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe$)  
   ).subscribe((data) => {
      this.data$.next(data);
   }
 }
```

data$ is using in view with *ngFor

```
*ngFor="let item of (data$ | async)">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is not calling directly `getData()` yourself but rather creating a Subject and stuffing search queries there. You can then use the Subject to create a chain that can unsubscribe from the previous requests:

```
private s$ = new Subject();
private result$ = s$.pipe(
  takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe$),
  switchMap(reqParams => this.endpointsService.getData(reqParams)),
);

getData(reqParams) {
  this.s$.next(reqParams);
}
```

Then in your template:

```
*ngFor="let item of (result$ | async)">
```

The `switchMap` operator will unsubscribe from its inner Observable on every emission from its source.

Ideally you can also use `debounceTime()` before `switchMap` to avoid even creating so many request.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to wait a certain period of time after a user interaction for the table to not change sorting and then apply the function?

You could do so with `debounceTime()`

```
 this.getData() {
   this.endpointsService.getData(reqParams).pipe(
      takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe$),
      debounceTime(1000), 
      distinctUntilChanged()
   ).subscribe((data) => {
      this.data$.next(data);
   }
 }
```

`debounceTime(1000)` will wait for the sorting to be unchanged for 1 second, then it will fetch data

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50740491/4091337

Comment: in this situation, debounceTime(1000) is not affected to the server request, because the request will fire and only after it debounceTime, or I'm wrong?

Comment: Here is an explanation of debounceTime: https://medium.com/aviabird/rxjs-reducing-number-of-api-calls-to-your-server-using-debouncetime-d71c209a4613. Yes the `getData` call will only be executed if debounceTime allows so

Comment: Yes, but it seems that I need to use debounceTime before the call to api.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using Delay operator.

**endpointsService:**

```
getData(){
  return this.http.get(url).pipe(
    delay(500)
  )
}
```

**Component:**

```
this.getData() {
   this.endpointsService.getData(reqParams).pipe(
      takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe$)
   ).subscribe((data) => {
      this.data$.next(data);
   }
 }
```