# Horizontal scroll event in Angular 8?

Tags: angular, scroll, horizontal-scrolling

Elaborating on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53998080/how-to-scroll-with-router-navigation-in-angular-7) threat, I have managed to navigate the routes through a `scroll` event in my App! My issue, I need it to work only when one is scrolling horizontally and not vertically, is that a way of doing that in Angular 8?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the host listener feature to identify the scroll event,

```
 @HostListener('scroll', ['$event']) private onScroll($event:Event):void {
    console.log($event.srcElement.scrollLeft, $event.srcElement.scrollTop);
 };
```

If there is change in scrollLeft, that denotes the horizontal scrolling event.

Answer (score 0):

**We can use `(scroll)="myFunction()"` to detect `scroll` in angular...**

In `component.html`

```
<div class="container" (scroll)="onScroll($event)">
  <div class="content">
    // Some content 
  </div>
</div>
```

In `component.ts`

```
onScroll(event: Event) {
  console.log(event);
  // write your logic here
}
```