# Angular 6 correctly initialize custom input component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular5, angular6

I was trying to create a custom input component with `debounce`, so I followed [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40777621/9775661)

`Debounce` works, but at the beginning the input value is not correctly set to the input component.

This is how I implemented it:

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { DebInputComponent } from './deb-input/deb-input.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
  test:string ='test';
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
  <deb-input [(ngModel)]="test" type="text" label="Test" ngDefaultControl>
  </deb-input>
<div>{{test}}</div>
```

**deb-input.component.ts**

```
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { debounceTime, distinctUntilChanged } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Component, Input }   from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'deb-input',
  templateUrl: './deb-input.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./deb-input.component.css'],
  providers: []
})

export class DebInputComponent {
    @Input() label: string;
    @Input() type: string="text";
    @Input() model: string;
    modelChanged: Subject<string> = new Subject<string>();

    constructor() {
     this.modelChanged
      .pipe(debounceTime(1000))
      .pipe(distinctUntilChanged())
      .subscribe(newValue => {this.model = newValue;
        console.log(this.model)});
    }

    changed(text: string) {
        this.modelChanged.next(text);
    }
}
```

**deb-input.component.html**

```
 <div>
 <span>{{label}}</span>
 <input [(ngModel)]='model' (ngModelChange)='changed($event)' [type]='type' ngDefaultControl/>
</div>
```

How can I make sure that `model` inside `deb-input` is correctly set to "test"?

Comment: You should use ControlValueAccessor - https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor if you want to implement custom form control.. this is the recommended way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `ngmodel` whereas you should use the name of  your component input

```
<deb-input [model]="test" type="text" label="Test" ngDefaultControl>
  </deb-input>
```

#### Edit

If you want a two way binding for your component, just add a `eventEmitter` to your component like this:

```
@Input() model: string;
@Output() modelChange = new EventEmitter<string>();
modelChanged: Subject<string> = new Subject<string>();
@Output() modelChangeEvt = new EventEmitter<string>();

 constructor() {
 this.modelChanged
  .pipe(debounceTime(1000))
  .pipe(distinctUntilChanged())
  .subscribe(newValue => {this.model = newValue;
    this.modelChangeEvt.emit(newValue);
    console.log(this.model)});
}
```

Then use the 2 way binding in HTML:

```
<deb-input [(model)]="test" type="text" label="Test" ngDefaultControl></deb-input>
```

Comment: So easy, great :)