# Directive event not being received by the component

Tags: angular-directive, angular7

I have a user search feature with a debounce directive on the search term field:

```
<mat-form-field>
    <input matInput [(ngModel)]="searchTerm" (appOnDebounce)="search($event)" placeholder="Search..." autocomplete="off">
</mat-form-field>
```

It is supposed to call the method:

```
search(searchTerm: string): void {
  console.log('Searching for ' + searchTerm);
}
```

The directive is implemented as:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[ngModel][appOnDebounce]'
})
export class DebounceDirective implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  @Output()
  public debounceEvent: EventEmitter<string>;

  @Input()
  public debounceTime = 300;

  private isFirstChange = true;
  private subscription: Subscription;

  constructor(public model: NgControl) {
    this.debounceEvent = new EventEmitter<string>();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = this.model.valueChanges
      .debounceTime(this.debounceTime)
      .distinctUntilChanged()
      .subscribe((modelValue: string) => {
        if (this.isFirstChange) {
          this.isFirstChange = false;
        } else {
          console.log(modelValue);
          this.debounceEvent.emit(modelValue);
        }
      });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }

}
```

The directive correctly emits the events as the logger statement shows the typed in string, but the `search(searchTerm: string): void {}` method is never called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the decarator of the debounceEvent property like this

```
@Output('appOnDebounce')
public debounceEvent: EventEmitter<any>;
```

Please see here the sample solution https://ng2-debounce-sample.stackblitz.io

Comment: The funny thing is that `tslint` in my `VSCode` IDE complains with `[tslint] @Outputs should not be renamed (no-output-rename)
(property) DebounceDirective.debounceEvent: EventEmitter<string>`
`

Comment: Instead I renamed my output variable and it also works fine `@Output()
  public appOnDebounce: EventEmitter<string>;
`