# two related autocomplete in angular 6

Tags: angular, search, autocomplete

I'm new to angular and I want to implement a search according to two related autocomplete input field
I have an array of objects:

```
holders: Holder[] = [
 { name: 'hanna', nationalId: 310, customerNumber: '123' },
 { name: 'jack', nationalId: 320, customerNumber: '124' },
 { name: 'sara', nationalId: 320, customerNumber: '125' },
];
```

in one of the fields I wanna enter the name and in the other one enter the nationalId

and then I wanna have autocomplete list of holders appear according to the fields
any body can help?

Comment: You may use debounce on your second field `nationalId` & filter on both conditions accordingly. Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32051273/angular-and-debounce)