# How to call function in debounceTime

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have two different subject subscriptions for different events which call the same function

```
subject1.subscribe(
_ => callFunction();
);

subject2.subscribe(
_ => callFunction();
);
```

i need that callFunction () is not to be invoked more than once every second, how can i do this behavior with rxjs?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular and debounce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32051273/angular-and-debounce)

Answer (score 2):

You have to combine your observables. If they're finished, use `forkJoin`, else `combineLatest` :

```
combineLatest(s1, s2).pipe(debounceTime(1000)).subscribe(([r1, r2]) => ...);
```