# Prevent execution based on previously emitted value

Tags: rxjs

If my typeahead gets an empty search result, any subsequent query with a norrowed down search query should be prevented. E.g. if the search for '*red*' returns empty, a search for '*redcar*' makes no sense.

I tried using pairwise() and scan() operator. Code snippet:

```
import { tap, switchMap, filter, pairwise, scan, map } from 'rxjs/operators';

this.searchForm.get('search').valueChanges
  .pipe(
    switchMap( queryString => this.backend.search(queryString))
  )
  .subscribe()
```

**Update**
Given a simplified scenario: There is only the term '*apple*' in the *backend*. The user is typing the search string (the request is not aborted by the switchMap()):

1. 'a' -------> backend call returns 'apple'
2. 'ap' ------> backend call returns 'apple'
3. 'app' -----> backend call returns 'apple'
4. 'appl' ----> backend call returns 'apple'
5. 'apple' ---> backend call returns 'apple'
6. 'apple p' -----> backend call returns EMPTY
7. 'apple pi' ----> backend call returns EMPTY
8. 'apple pie' ---> backend call returns EMPTY

The backend calls for 7. and 8. are unnecessary, because 6. already returns EMPTY. Therfore any subsequent call could be omitted. In my opinion some memoization is needed.

I would like to prevent unnecessary backend calls (http). Is there any way to achieve this in rxjs?

Comment: skipWhile(val => val === 'red') https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/skipwhile.html

Comment: Thanks for the update. Do you only want to block calls when you return _empty_? Because the way it's phrased, not only are 7,8 unnecessary, but 2 (perhaps 3) through 5 as well.

Comment: I'll just leave this here, while it _does not do exactly_ what you are looking for, this is normally the way people _achieve a similar functionality,_ and might be worth looking at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32051273/angular-and-debounce

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an interesting use-case and one of a very few situations where `mergeScan` is useful.

Basically, you want to remember the previous search term and the previous remote call result and based on their combination you'll decide whether you should make another remote call or just return `EMPTY`.

```
import { of, EMPTY, Subject, forkJoin } from 'rxjs'; 
import { mergeScan, tap, filter, map } from 'rxjs/operators';

const source$ = new Subject();
// Returns ['apple'] only when the entire search string is contained inside the word "apple".
// 'apple'.indexOf('app') returns 0
// 'apple'.indexOf('apple ap') returns -1
const makeRemoteCall = (str: string) =>
  of('apple'.indexOf(str) === 0 ? ['apple'] : []).pipe(
    tap(results => console.log(`remote returns`, results)),
  );

source$
  .pipe(
    tap(value => console.log(`searching "${value}""`)),
    mergeScan(([acc, previousValue], value: string) => {
      // console.log(acc, previousValue, value);
      return (acc === null || acc.length > 0 || previousValue.length > value.length)
        ? forkJoin([makeRemoteCall(value), of(value)]) // Make remote call and remember the previous search term
        : EMPTY;
    }, [null, '']),
    map(acc => acc[0]), // Get only the array of responses without the previous search term
    filter(results => results.length > 0), // Ignore responses that didn't find any results
  )
  .subscribe(results => console.log('results', results));

source$.next('a');
source$.next('ap');
source$.next('app');
source$.next('appl');
source$.next('apple');
source$.next('apple ');
source$.next('apple p');
source$.next('apple pi');
source$.next('apple pie');

setTimeout(() => source$.next('app'), 3000);
setTimeout(() => source$.next('appl'), 4000);
```

Live demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-do457

Notice that after searching for `"apple "` there are no more remote calls. Also, after 3s  when you try searching a different term "'app'" it does make a remote call again.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [filter](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/filter.html) operator:

```ts
this.searchForm.get('search').valueChanges.pipe(
  filter(query => query)
  switchMap(query => this.backend.search(queryString))
)
```

You can try out this mechanism here: [RxJS-Editor](https://rxviz.com/examples/custom)

Code-share did not work so you get the code here:

```ts
const { of } = Rx;
const { filter } = RxOperators;

of('foo1', 'foo2', undefined, undefined, 'foo3').pipe(
  filter(value => value)  
)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think filter is the appripiate solution. I updated the question to give some clarification.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you want to keep all failed searches and check whether current search would fail also if HTTP is called. I cant think of any elegant way of having this in one stream, but with two streams:

```
_failedStreams = new Subject();
failedStreams$ = _failedStreams.asObservable().pipe(
  scan((acc, curr) => [...acc, curr], []),
  startWith('')
);

this.searchForm.get('search').valueChanges
  .pipe(
    withLatestFrom(failedStreams$),
    switchMap([queryString, failedQueries] => {
      return iif(() => failedQueries.find(failed => failed.startsWith(queryString)) ?
        of('Not found') :
        callBackend(queryString);
      )
    }
  )
  .subscribe()

callBackend(queryString) {
  this.backend.search(queryString)).pipe(
    .catchError(err => if(error.status===404) {
      this._failedStreams.next(queryString);
      // do something with error stream, for ex:
      throwError(error.status)
    }
  )
}
```

*Code is not tested, but you get the idea*

Comment: That's exaclty what I would like to achieve. I give it a try and provide some feedback tomorrow.

Comment: Hi Julius, though your solutions works, I think mergeScan() from the accepeted answer is the "missing link" to solve the problem in a more rxjs-way.

Comment: Yep, its the best answer +1. But I have a bad feeling one of your colleagues might shoot himself

Comment: Some solutions are too smart for real world use. Perhaps in rxjs more than in others. I keep that in mind.