# Angular, to many API calls on input 'on-change'

Tags: javascript, angular, onchange

I am using angular 8.

There is one auto-complete input and if it's value changes I have to make API call and load new suggestions for this input.

```
  //In Template

  <autocomplate [suggestions]="suggestions" (filterChange)="filterChange($event)"></autocomplate>



  //In Component

  filterChange(e) {
    console.log(e)
    this.loadSubscriptions(e ? { 'filterItem.name': e  } : {})
  }

  loadSubscriptions(params) {
     if (this.suggestionsSubscriber) this.suggestionsSubscriber.unsubscribe()
     this.suggestionsSubscriber = this.suggestionsService.loadData(params).subscribe(
        data => this.suggestions = data
     })
  }
```

Everything works fine, but the problem is when user types fast application makes to many requests.

Can I somehow delay requests if user types fast? for example, while the user is typing don't make API calls on every change, and if the user stops typing then make API call.

Or if you have a better way to solve this problem, please share.

Comment: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/throttletime.html

Comment: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/debouncetime.html

Comment: You can implement like when user stop typing It will call API, Refer this http://blog.sodhanalibrary.com/2016/10/trigger-event-when-user-finishes-typing.html#.XThI2egzaUk

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/practical-observable-usage

Answer (score 3):

Use RXJS denounceTime operator. Simply chain it to your Observable.

Whenever debounceTime receives an event, it waits a designated amount of time to see if another event comes down the pipe. If it does, it restarts its timer. When enough time has passed without another event streaming in, it emits the latest event.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to use [throttle](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#throttle) or [debounce](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#debounce). You can write your own implementation for those or use library such as lodash.

Debounce using latest Rxjs can be a work around. Please see below for implementation.

[Angular and debounce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32051273/angular-and-debounce)

Comment: There was an addition to my answer that it can be handled with RXjs operators as well and I completely agree with @Harshad Vekariya

Answer (score 1):

I also had a same problem, so i put my code inside setTimeout as below

```
  filterChange(e) {
    console.log(e)
    setTimeout(()=>{
      this.loadSubscriptions(e ? { 'filterItem.name': e  } : {})
    },2000);
  }
```

Now if you type very fast then it will not call the loadSubscriptions at that time. it will call after 2 sec.
You can configure the time according to your choice. 
 I hope This will helps you.

Comment: That's not real solution by angular way but it can be hack. :)

Comment: Yes it is. i used it our react application and its working so well  :)

Comment: It will surely works. No offense, but angular have better way to handle.

Comment: def works as a hack, but the right solution would be to use debounceTime() which is the rxjs way.