# p-calendar angular 6 event onClick doesnt fire (and others events)

Tags: angular, primeng

I want to call a method when I open a  component, so I've tested some method, no one works just (onSelect) event works. Here is a part of the code :

```
<p-calendar id="idCalendarDateExportFrom" [showIcon]="true" [(ngModel)]="dateChoosenProd" readonlyInput="true" [showTime]="true" dateFormat="dd/mm/yy" [locale]="fr"  
(onClick)="moveDate(1)" (onSelect)="moveDate(0)">
</p-calendar>
```

In ts file :

```
public moveDate(position: Number){
        if(position === 1){
            this.marginTop = "400px";
        } else {
            this.marginTop = "0px";
        }
}
```

I've tried also onclick without uppercase, onmouseover, ...

I use Angular 6

Comment: Look under Events at the [documentation](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/calendar), should be `(onShow)`.

Comment: i've tried also onShow

Comment: Can you reproduce your problem in a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/)?

Comment: I'll try to put it un Stackblitz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`calendar` component of PrimeNG [uses](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/master/src/app/components/calendar/calendar.ts) an `input` tag to display the date input box.  So theoretically, you could bind to it's mouse events. The following works partially as requested. But for some reason, the `onmousedown` event is triggered again when the `onSelect` event is triggered.

```
<p-calendar [(ngModel)]="value" [locale]="en" (mousedown)="moveDate(1)" (onSelect)="moveDate(0)"></p-calendar>
```

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/p-calendar-hfhe69)

Answer (score 0):

Check the Events table in [primefaces calendar docs](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/calendar)

E.g.:

> onShow    event: Animation event  Callback to invoke when datepicker panel
> is visible.

or

> onSelect  value: Selected value   Callback to invoke when a date is
> selected. Note that this event is not called when the value is entered
> from the input manually.

See [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-calendar-wrapper?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdatepicker%2Fdatepicker.component.ts)

Comment: I the test file there are two events: onBlur and select , which one i must use? thank's

Answer (score 0):

```
<p-calendar 
  [(ngModel)]="testDate" 
  (onSelect)="selectDate()" 
  (onBlur)="blurDate()">
</p-calendar>
```

If i used both `onBlur` and `onSelect` on the same input with `[(ngModel)]` they **both** get called after picking day from calendar, but inside `onBlur` variable inside ngModel was undefined! Inside `onSelect` same variable had picked day. Some [debounce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32051273/angular-2-and-debounce) could be good for this.

But as documentation say, `onSelect` won't be called if you enter value by hand, then just `onBlur` is called - but variable inside `ngModel` is updated to picked value!

Also, **neither** `onSelect` or `onBlur` called when you enter value and press Enter (at least in my environment), until user click outside element and loose input focus.

Possible solution:

Use Angular [FormGroup](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup)

HTML template

```
<p-calendar formControlName="testDate"></p-calendar>
```

JS

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
        testDate:   [new Date(Date.now())],
    });

    this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(formData => {
        console.log('Picked date:', formData.testDate);
        // expected output - picked date as Date.prototype
    });
}
```

This is working when:

- picking date from calendar popup
- changing value manually (again, some [debounce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32051273/angular-2-and-debounce) could be useful)

Answer (score 0):

None of these answers seem to work for me in Angular 13. All I had to do was define the functions correctly and the events started firing. This is not obvious from the documentation or lack of example code. The key seemed to be making sure you pass the event object through to the function and not some arbitrary value as in the OP example code.

HTML:

```
<p-calendar [formControlName]="theControlName"
     (onSelect)="onSelect($event)"
     (onChange)="onSelect($event)"
     [showIcon]="true" appendTo="body">
</p-calendar>
```

Component TypeScript:

```
onSelect(event): void {
    console.log('onSelect called',event);
}
```