# How to access values from subscribed angular form?

Tags: angular

I have an angular form with fields such as first name, last name, email, etc. I am subscribing to the values being changed and would like to access and show the values in the html as sort of a review/confirm and submit feature.

```
this.addEmployeeForm.valueChanges.subscribe(
  values => {
    console.log("VALUES", values);
    if(values.hasOwnProperty('firstName')){
      console.log(values.firstName)
      this.defaultData.push(values.firstName);
    }
  }
)
```

I was hoping to have these values in the default data, then loop through the default data array. The problem I am having is, since it is a subscription, it pushes every single key change into the array. Is there nay way I can access the final full name?

Answer (score 0):

You can either add a debounce time to the subscription, or create a form to which you subscribe only when submitted, so that you eventually get all the data.
Adding debounce is the easiest to achieve given your code, and [heres a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32051273/angular-and-debounce)

Putting your code inside a form then subscribing to that form so that you get all the values within it is probably the best option, but might be slightly outside the scope of your question