# Avoid http request spam

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a toggle switch that makes an http PATCH request when it is triggered. Below you can see how it looks like:

[image]
[image]

The template:

```
<div id="toggle-status-btn-container">
    <div class="slider" [ngClass]="{'to-right': !shopIsOpen}"></div>
    <div class="label-container">
        <label class="store-opened" (click)="updateShopSlotsStatus(true)" [ngClass]="{'toggled-opened-text': !shopIsOpen}">OPENED</label>
    </div>
    <div class="label-container">
        <label class="store-closed" (click)="updateShopSlotsStatus(false)" [ngClass]="{'toggled-closed-text': !shopIsOpen}">CLOSED</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

It works great, but as of right now the user can spam this toggle switch, triggering multiple http requests in a row.

What can I do to prevent this behaviour? I don't want to trigger an http request if the user is spamming this toggle switch. Maybe there's a way to only trigger the last one? Since I'm very new to RxJs I don't really know how to solve this.

Here is the method that is called by the click event, in the component .ts:

```
updateShopSlotsStatus(isOpen: boolean){
    this.shopIsOpen = isOpen;
    this.apiService.updateShopSlotsStatus(isOpen, this.weekDay).subscribe();
}
```

And the http request, in a service file:

```
updateShopSlotsStatus(isOpen: boolean, weekDay: string){
    const endpoint = this.url + "shipping/" + this.webzineId + "/delivery_slots" + "/";
    return this.http.patch(endpoint, {"slots": { [weekDay] : { "enabled": isOpen }}});
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 2+ and debounce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32051273/angular-2-and-debounce) (The "thing" you're looking for is called _debouncing_. There are many old answers in this thread, but appropriate recent ones as well.)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! I'm having a hard time figuring out how I can adapt some of those answers to my question, since many of them are about form controls and inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll perhaps want to use a combination of `BehaviorSubject` and `switchMap` like in [this StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8ynh86?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).

Here, I've bound the open and close button to a function that changes a `BehaviorSubject`s value like so:

template:

```
  <button
    (click)="updateShopSlotsStatus(true)"
    [ngClass]="{'selected': shopSlotStatus$ | async}"
  >
    OPEN
  </button>
  <button
    (click)="updateShopSlotsStatus(false)"
    [ngClass]="{'selected': !(shopSlotStatus$ | async)}"
  >
    CLOSED
  </button>
```

ts:

```
  updateShopSlotsStatus(isOpen: boolean) {
    this.shopSlotStatusSubject$.next(isOpen);
  }
```

You could then watch for changes on the `BehaviorSubject` like so:

```
  private shopSlotStatusSubject$: BehaviorSubject<
    boolean
  > = new BehaviorSubject(false);

  // shared so only one subscription is maintained
  private readonly shopSlotStatus$ = this.shopSlotStatusSubject$
    .asObservable()
    .pipe(share());

  readonly changeSlotStatus$ = this.shopSlotStatus$.pipe(
    // you could introduce a debounceTime here if you wanted
    // debounceTime(500),
    tap(() => (this.changingStatus = true)),
    // faked API call here
    switchMap(status => this.appService.updateShopSlotsStatus(status)),
    tap(() => (this.changingStatus = false))
  );
```

The `switchMap` operator will cancel any inflight observables should the source (in this case the `changeSlotStatus$` observable) emit.

I've included imports for `exhaustMap` and `mergeMap` on the Stackblitz. Change `switchMap` to both of those operators to see how they work differently. `exhaustMap` will ignore all subsequent emissions until the one in progress has completed, and `mergeMap` will fire off as many requests as button presses. I'll leave it up to you to decide which approach is best! You can learn more at [learn rxjs.](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/) I would suggest reading up on RxJS and the different operators and how you can compose them using `pipe`. RxJS is good stuff.

You could then also bind to the `changingStatus` bool if you wanted to disable the button being pressed while a request is in flight.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Thank you for the detailed answer!

Comment: You’re very welcome. RxJS was extremely daunting for me at first. Stick at it.